# CSS Paragraph is not positioned correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, message

Hey guys i have a problem with my style.css
Actually i want the info message to be centered but its just hanging at the left side of my side...

Here a picture:

[image]

Here my CSS:

```
*{
    font-family: arial;
}

#title{
    color: dodgerblue;
}

form{
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

form input{
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
}

#textfield{
    padding: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}

#submitButton{
    width: 30%;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

#submitButton:hover{
    padding: 11px;
    background-color: royalblue;
}

#info{
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color:lightblue;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 30%;
}
```

and here my Form:

```
<form>
  <h2 id="title">Registration</h2>
  <label>
    <input type="text" id="textfield" defaultValue={this.props.user.username} placeholder="Username" ref="username" onChange={this.handleUsername.bind(this)} required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="password" id="textfield" defaultValue={this.props.user.password} placeholder="Password" ref="password" onChange={this.handlePassword.bind(this)} required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="password" id="textfield" defaultValue {this.props.user.password} placeholder="Repeat Password" ref="password2" required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="text" id="textfield" defaultValue={this.props.user.firstname} placeholder="Firstname" ref="firstname" onChange={this.handleFirstname.bind(this)} required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="text" id="textfield" defaultValue={this.props.user.lastname} placeholder="Lastname" ref="lastname" onChange={this.handleLastname.bind(this)} required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="email" id="textfield" defaultValue={this.props.user.email} placeholder="Email" ref="email" onChange={this.handleEmail.bind(this)} required/>
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <a href="/login">Already have an account?</a>
  </label><br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitButton" onClick={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}/>   
  {info}
</form>
```

Would be great if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info message paragraph is not in the html you pasted above - if you want it centered, make sure it goes inside the `form` tags. Otherwise give it `margin: 10px auto;` instead of `margin: 10px;` and you're good to go.

`margin: 10px;` is a shorthand property for `margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;` - top, right, bottom, left (TRouBLe) meaning that your `.info` paragraph gets 10px from top and left and the the right one is set to auto implicitly.

`margin: 10px auto;` is a shorthand property for `margin: 10px auto; 10px auto`, so you give the element margin 10px top and bottom and left right is set to auto - it will center any block element once you set an explicit width on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the below code

```
#info
{
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It works in such way because this button https://www.screencast.com/t/4VldbfP82LS2 is out of form. On form we have text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at css flex alignment. It's the most intuitive way to layout elements responsivly:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything to be placed in the center of the screen, then set it's CSS  `margin` property to `auto`.